# nginx: location tilde regex vs path

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location, proxypass

What is the difference between these 2 nginx directives?

`location ^~ /sub-directory`

`location /sub-directory`

In the following code block, use `proxy_pass` to redirect, if that makes a difference.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/location that depends on other locations you have

Answer (score 1):

Consider the below nginx config

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location ^~ /sub-directory {
        echo "^~ /sub-directory";
    }

    location /sub-director
    {
        echo "/sub-director";
    }

    location ~* /sub-* {
        echo "~* /sub-*";
    }
}
```

I ran above using a docker container

```
sudo docker run -p 80:80 -v $PWD/nginx.conf:/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf openresty/openresty
```

Now consider the below curl statements

```
$ curl http://192.168.33.100/sub-director/abc
~* /sub.*

 $ curl http://192.168.33.100/sub-director/
~* /sub.*

 $ curl http://192.168.33.100/sub-director
~* /sub.*

 $ curl http://192.168.33.100/sub-directory
^~ /sub-directory

 $ curl http://192.168.33.100/sub-directory/
^~ /sub-directory

 $ curl http://192.168.33.100/sub-directory/abc
^~ /sub-directory
```

As you can see I cannot by any way reach the below location block

```
    location /sub-director
    {
        echo "/sub-director";
    }
```

Because the regular expression overrides this block. But I can still reach

```
    location ^~ /sub-directory {
        echo "^~ /sub-directory";
    }
```

So that is the difference. When you use `^~` and a location is matched then regular expression base locations are not evaluated at all.